# How I can add a new Tablet in `TInkTablets` control

Tags: delphi, tablet

How I can add a new Tablet in `TInkTablets` control. Currently the Tablet's `PlugAndPlayId` is `SCREEN`. I need to add a new device. How is it possible. I'm using Delphi 2010.
Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the TInkTablets it is automatically filled with available tablets.
You cannot add some the way you want. A new Tablet have to be installed system wide before being accessible in the Tablets collection.